# Configured APN in module is different from sim

Tags: gprs, apn

Lately I bought a device with a GPRS module. This module is configured with an APN "internet". My sim cards have their own APNs which are obviously different from "internet" and specific to the operators. I can't change the configurations on the device and I don't know why the APN redirection is not working. Any idea on how to proceed in order to connect the device ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by using a sim card with an APN "internet".